# Rundeck run certain steps in parallel

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to run set of rundeck steps in a workflow in parallel?

Example:

```
==> means sequential

|| means parallel

Ex: Step 1 ==> Step 2.A || Step 2.B ==> Step 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature of Ruleset Workflow Strategy is a plugin that is only available in the Rundeck Enterprise Version. [Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html#ruleset-workflow-strategy-plugin) you can find the official documentation

In the Rundeck community version, you can set the parallel strategy to run all steps at the same time.